# What causes Spring Security to return a 401 status code for permitted requests?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I employ the OAuth2 resource server dependency alongside Spring Security 6.2. While employing basic authentication, it confines execution to solely GET methods, even when permitting all request types. To resolve this, the CSRF protection needs to be deactivated.

Nevertheless, when switching to JWT authentication, the issue remains unresolved despite disabling CSRF protection. Only GET methods are permitted, whereas other methods (POST, PUT, etc.) result in a 401 Unauthorized status.

***SecurityConfig.java***

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

@Autowired
UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;
@Autowired
PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

@Value("${jwt.secretKey}")
private String secretKey;


@Bean
SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity.sessionManagement(s -> s.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize ->
                    authorize.anyRequest().permitAll());
    httpSecurity.oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2) -> oauth2.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()));
    return httpSecurity.build();
}

@Bean
public JwtEncoder jwtEncoder() {
    return new NimbusJwtEncoder(new ImmutableSecret<>(secretKey.getBytes()));
}


@Bean
public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getBytes(), "RSA");
    return NimbusJwtDecoder.withSecretKey(secretKeySpec).macAlgorithm(MacAlgorithm.HS512).build();
}

@Bean
AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    return new ProviderManager(daoAuthenticationProvider);
}
}
```

[Response Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sz8ci.png)
[Request Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXQDi.png)

```
2023-08-23T22:15:43.044+01:00 DEBUG 7880 --- [nio-8081-exec-1]         
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST 
/auth/login
2023-08-23T22:15:43.051+01:00 DEBUG 7880 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] 
o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set 
SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-08-23T22:15:43.052+01:00 DEBUG 7880 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] 
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured POST /auth/login
```

Comment: That you didnt post the request with headers. You shoud do it. see my first comment.

Comment: @dur done and sorry.

Comment: Your request doesn't contain a JWT token, so you are not authenticated.

Comment: Your are calling login endpoint without a JWT token.